# Why am I getting an error when I have done the same thing for the other two racers?

Tags: python

I am new to python and ran into an issue. It states "racer_3.down()
TypeError: pendown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

I'm trying to create a racing turtles simulation. I will include the code that I have written so far.

```
import turtle
import random

window = turtle.Screen()

racer_1 = turtle.Turtle()
racer_1.up()
racer_1.shape("turtle")
racer_1.color(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
racer_1.goto(-200, 100)
racer_1.down()
racer_1.stamp()

racer_2 = turtle.Turtle()
racer_2.up()
racer_2.shape("turtle")
racer_2.color(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
racer_2.goto(-200, 0)
racer_2.down()
racer_2.stamp()

racer_3 = turtle.Turtle
racer_3.down()
racer_3.shape('turtle')
racer_3.color(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
racer_3.goto(-200,-100)
racer_3.up()
racer_3.stamp()

for i in range(10):
    racer_1.forward(random.randint(1, 40))
    racer_1.dot()
    racer_2.forward(random.randint(1, 40))
    racer_2.dot()
    racer_3.forward(random.randint(1, 40))
    racer_3.dot()
    
if racer_1.xcor() > racer_2.xcor > racer_3.xcor():
    print("Turtle racer #1 wins!")
else:
    print("Turtle racer #2 wins!")
    print("Turtle racer #3 wins!")
                      
                      
window.exitonclick()
```

Comment: You forgot the brackets on `turtle.Turtle` when assigning `racer_3` - so it points to the class rather than an instance of it. As a consequence you are trying to call the unbound class method rather than an instance method that automatically gets the instance as its first argument - hence the complaint about missing positional argument - but that may be too much detail, so the bottom line is that you just needed to do `racer_3 = turtle.Turtle()`

Comment: you should learn how to create functions because you could write this code only once and run it three times (with different argumens) and maybe then you will not make this mistake.